# What XR plugin should i use for creating a VR project on unity for android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

[image]

In case of Android, here are the three options that I'm getting to choose from. I wanna create a VR project for a cheap normal VR headset. Which plugin do I use so that it supports most of the VR headsets?

Answer (score 0):

ARCore is developed by Google for android devices. Use that.